# Monitoring Updates over Time Frames and/or SQL Query with Regex counting dates within string

Tags: sql, regex, database-design

This is probably a fork in the road question.  I have a journal blog that date stamps a continuation of a single field within a record.

Example:

Proj #1 (ID): Notes (memo field:) 10/12/2012 - visited site. 10/11/2012 - updated information. 10/11/2012 - call client. 10/10/2012 - Input information.

Proj #2 (ID): Notes (memo field:) 10/10/12 - visited site. 10/10/2012 - call client. 10/9/2012 - Input information. 10/1/2012 - Started project. etc etc...

I need to count how many updates where made over a specific time frame.  I know I can create a hidden field and add + 1 everytime there is an update which is useful for an OVERALL update count... but how can i keep track of number of updates over the last 5 days.  Like the example above you may update it twice in one day and I may not care about updates made 2 weeks ago.

I think I need to create an SQL that counts the number of "dates" since 10/10/12 or since 10/2/12 etc.

I have done the SQL: SELECT memo FROM Projects WHERE memo IN ('%10/10/12%', '%10/9/2012%' etc)
and then the Len(memoStringCombined) - Len(Replace(searchword""etc)/Len(searchword) and it works fine for countings a single date...  but if I have count multiple dates over 30 days it gets to be quite cumbersome to keep rewriting each search word.  Is there a regex or obj that can loop through this for me?

Otherwise any other suggestions for counting updates between time frames would be greatly appreciated.

BTW - I can't really justify creating a new table dedicated to tracking updates because there will be 100's of updates for close to 10,000 records which means the update tracking table will be more monstrous than the data... or am I wrong with that idea too?

Comment: If you control the software writing to this table, it will be much easier to search if you have a master project table and a related update_log table. If you just used it to track dates you'd need a project_id and an update_date column. For day precision, most dbms have a date type that takes 4 bytes, and the project_id will probably be similar. 8 bytes * 1,000,000 rows is 8MB. Hardly a lot of space for most devices that can use a database server.

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: good to know on the size.  I have taken control of the data management.  It was/is on access and I was going to convert it to mySql.